# GOLang Scanf error

Tags: go

When using Scanf twice the first time it gets the useres input but the second time it does not and returns out of the function. This is only a problem when running on Windows. When I run it on my Mac it works as expected first asking the uers for their username then their password. Below is the code in questions. I am not sure why it works fine on Mac but not on Windows. Any help in advance is appreciated. Thank you.

```
func credentials() (string, string) {

    var username string
    var password string

    fmt.Print("Enter Username: ")
    fmt.Scanf("%s", &username)

    fmt.Print("Enter Password: ")
    fmt.Scanf("%s", &password)

    return username, password
}
```

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Scanf is a bit finicky in that it uses spaces as a separator, and (at least for me) is rather unintuitive. Bufio does a good job of abstracting some of that:

```
func credentials() (string, string) {
    reader := bufio.NewReader(os.Stdin)

    fmt.Print("Enter Username: ")
    username, _ := reader.ReadString('\n')

    fmt.Print("Enter Password: ")
    password, _ := reader.ReadString('\n')

    return strings.TrimSpace(username), strings.TrimSpace(password) // ReadString() leaves a trailing newline character
}
```

Comment: I tried using bufio earlier and trimming the spaces was not working when using the \n as a dillimiter. I was actually able to solve it by just using Scan instead of Scanf. Thank you for your answer.

Answer (score 1):

You need to add newlines:

```
package main
import "fmt"

func main() {
   var user, pass string
   fmt.Scanf("%s\n", &user)
   fmt.Println(user)
   fmt.Scanf("%s\n", &pass)
   fmt.Println(pass)
}
```

alternatively, you can just use `Scanln`:

```
package main
import "fmt"

func main() {
   var user, pass string
   fmt.Scanln(&user)
   fmt.Println(user)
   fmt.Scanln(&pass)
   fmt.Println(pass)
}
```

https://golang.org/pkg/fmt#Scanln

Comment: Using your last example i'm getting this error: [type not a pointer: string