# Go program not waiting for input with scanf

Tags: go, input, scanf

I've found some sort of similar problems in c, but the solutions are c specific. package main

Here is a minimum working example of the code

```
import "fmt"

func main() {
  var mode string
  var base int
  for {
    fmt.Printf("(Base) [-->]: ")
    fmt.Scanf("%d", &base)
    fmt.Printf("(Mode) [-->]: ")
    fmt.Scanf("%s", &mode)
  }
}
```

My issue is that after asking for the mode input, it doesn't wait for input, and immediately skips to the beginning of the loop. Something like this:

```
(Base) [-->]: 5
(Mode) [-->]: (Base) [-->]:
```

Comment: Your code works for me, on my machine, with `5` as the input for `base` and `foo` for `mode`, without the behaviour you described. Are you sure you, on your machine, can reproduce the error with the code in the question? and with the *same* input? If you really do get the weird behaviour then try checking the errors returned from `Scanf`.

Comment: https://imgur.com/a/cWGETnp

Comment: I'm just about to try it in a different terminal emulator.

Comment: I've tried it, and it works on linux, but not windows. Doesn't work in powershell or cmd.exe. Maybe something to do with the different line breaks?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26536746/fmt-scanf-not-working-properly-in-go, https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13846522/golang-scanf-error, https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17401709/why-doesnt-fmt-scanf-in-go-wait-for-user-input

Comment: The \n one work for me. Odd that it still worked on linux though.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I had the same problem, change`fmt.Scanf("%d", &base)` to `fmt.Scanf("%d \n", &base)`. I think it's connected to output of Scanf() where extra newline not being consumed by first scanf. Above code may still work in some device without any errors.

```
import "fmt"

func main() {
  var mode string
  var base int
  for {
    fmt.Printf("(Base) [-->]: ")
    fmt.Scanf("%d \n", &base)
    fmt.Printf("(Mode) [-->]: ")
    fmt.Scanf("%s \n", &mode)
  }
}
```

Comment: Yes, this fixes the issue. I think that it may be because of the windows terminal, as it works on mac and linux on all of the terminal emulators I've tried.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `fmt.Scanln(&base)` instead of `fmt.Scanf("%d", &base)`:

```
import "fmt"

func main() {
    var mode string
    var base int
    for {
        fmt.Printf("(Base) [-->]: ")
        fmt.Scanln(&base)
        fmt.Printf("(Mode) [-->]: ")
        fmt.Scanln(&mode)
    }
}
```

Or `line, _ := bufio.NewReader(os.Stdin).ReadString('\n')` is a good alternative to reading the whole line.

For `fmt.Scanf()` newlines in the input must match newlines in the format.