# Handling command drift on golang

Tags: go

when entering data for the array from the user side. After entering n = 5 the end `a[0]` is automatically assigned to 0 and is ignored to continue typing `a[1]`. I tried on other machines and [replit](https://replit.com/join/pgisixpkkw-hilng) but it seems to only happen on my computer. I also tried uninstalling and reinstalling golang but it didn't fix it

```golang
package main

import (
    "fmt"
)

func main() {
    var a = [100]int{}
    var n int
    fmt.Print("N = ")
    fmt.Scanf("%v", &n)
    for i := 0; i < n; i++ {
        fmt.Printf("a[%v] = ", i)
        fmt.Scanf("%v", &a[i])
    }
    for i := 0; i < n; i++ {
        fmt.Printf("%v ", a[i])
    }
    fmt.Println()
}
```

[image]

Comment: Does this answer your question? [GOLang Scanf error](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13846522/golang-scanf-error)

Answer (score 1):

This will solve the problem for you, it's important to debug in go language.

```
  var a = make([]int, 100)
        var n int = 5
        fmt.Print("N = ")
        fmt.Scanf("%v \n", &n)
        for i := 0; i < n; i++ {
            fmt.Printf("a[%v] = ", i)
            _, err := fmt.Scanf("%v \n", &a[i])
            if err != nil {
                fmt.Println("error", err)
            }
        }
        for i := 0; i < n; i++ {
            fmt.Printf("%v ", a[i])
        }
        fmt.Println()
```

https://pkg.go.dev/fmt#pkg-overview